# C# timer not starting?

Tags: c#, timer

I am not sure what went wrong, I coded a timer to delay a piece of code but it is just not starting. Hopefully, someone can offer me some insight whether it has anything to do with await / async.

```
private async void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.close() // closes form to prevent further input; is this why timer failed? 

    // Some codes
    Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => PDF.Merge(PDF.Copy(tblPDFs, Appendix, DestFolder), Appendix, DestFolder));
    string PDFresult = await task;

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;

    timer.Tick += new EventHandler((abc, def) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HOORAY!"); //<-- not firing! 
        timer.Stop();
    });

    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Well how far did you get in debugging it? Does the PDF Merge complete correctly? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Does `PDF.Merge` completes? Did you debug to see what happens?

Comment: Is the timer enabled? timer.Enabled = true;

Comment: @Chirag Not required. `timer.Start` does that for you.

Comment: The task completes and I managed to debug all the way to `timer.start()`. After which, it just ends... There is no pop up. It just so bizarre!

Comment: put a break point at the line MessageBox.Show

Comment: I did close the window before this. See updated code

Comment: Are you sure that the code in your timer callback isn't throwing? It rather looks like you're trying to fiddle with the UI from a `ThreadPool` thread.

Comment: Your mix of Task based asynchrony mixed with event based asynchrony is unusual... Why not `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead of reverting to a Timer?

Comment: What is the timer's namespace?

Comment: remove `this.close(); `

Comment: An interesting read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121226/MessageBoxes-and-worker-threads

Comment: @spender your suggestion of using await Task.Delay() worked! Thank you so much! Also, thanks for the link, I will read up on it. I am a beginner mashing things together to see what works. Still lots to learn.

Comment: Instead of adding the answer to your question, please either post the answer as an actual answer (you can answer and accept your own question), or have @spender post the answer (which you can then accept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @spender, I have removed the timer and used Task.Delay(), which worked:

```
private async void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.close() // closes form to prevent further input; is this why timer failed? 

    // Some codes
    Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => PDF.Merge(PDF.Copy(tblPDFs, Appendix, DestFolder), Appendix, DestFolder));
    string PDFresult = await task;

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // Codes you want to do. 
}
```